Next.js API Route Timing Out with Mongoose Query: Operation places.find() buffering timed out after 10000ms
I am working on a Next.js application where I need to query a MongoDB database using Mongoose. Despite ensuring the MongoDB connection is established, my queries keep timing out with the error: Operation places.find() buffering timed out after 10000ms.
Place.js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const placeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  country: String,
  population: Number,
  work: {
    pub: Number,
    pub_ratio: Number,
    languages: {
      primary: String,
      secondary: String,
    },
    avg: Number,
    attendance: Number,
  },
  culture: {
    food_type: String,
    climate: String,
    internet_penetration: String,
    transportation_infra: String,
    crime_rate: String,
    recreation: String,
  },
});

placeSchema.index({ 'culture.recreation': 1 });

const Place = mongoose.models.Place || mongoose.model('Place', placeSchema, 'places');

export default Place;

connectDB.js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const MONGO_URI = process.env.MONGO_URI || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/NG_DESTINATION';

if (!MONGO_URI) {
  throw new Error('Please define the MONGO_URI environment variable inside .env.local');
}

let cached = global.mongoose;

if (!cached) {
  cached = global.mongoose = { conn: null, promise: null };
}

async function connectDB() {
  console.log('Checking cached connection...');
  if (cached.conn) {
    console.log('Using cached connection');
    return cached.conn;
  }

  if (!cached.promise) {
    console.log('No cached promise found, creating new connection promise...');
    const opts = {
      bufferCommands: false,
      serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 50000, 
      socketTimeoutMS: 50000, 
    };

    cached.promise = mongoose.connect(MONGO_URI, opts).then((mongoose) => {
      console.log('MongoDB connected');
      return mongoose;
    }).catch(err => {
      console.error('MongoDB connection error:', err);
      throw err;
    });
  }

  try {
    cached.conn = await cached.promise;
    console.log('MongoDB connection established');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error awaiting connection promise:', error);
    throw error;
  }

  return cached.conn;
}

export default connectDB;

match-places.js
import connectDB from '../../../lib/connectDB';
import Place from '../../../backend/models/Place';

export default async (req, res) => {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    try {
      console.log("Connecting to database...");
      await connectDB();
      console.log("Connected to database");

      const userPreferences = req.body;
      console.log("User Preferences: ", userPreferences);

      console.log("Starting MongoDB query...");

      const places = await Place.find({}).limit(10);
      console.log("Places found: ", places);

      if (places.length === 0) {
        console.error("No places found.");
        return res.status(404).json({ error: "No places found." });
      }

      res.status(200).json({ places });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error during database operation: ", error);
      res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
    }
  } else {
    res.status(405).end(); // Method Not Allowed
  }
};

index.js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Box, ChakraProvider, Text } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Questionnaire from '../../components/Questionnaire';
import Results from '../../components/Results';

const Home = () => {
  const [place, setPlace] = useState(null);

  const handleSubmit = async (responses) => {
    try {
      console.log("Home - Submitting Responses:", responses);
      const response = await axios.post('/api/match-places', responses); 
      console.log("Home - API Response:", response.data);
      setPlace(response.data.recommendation);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching recommendation:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <ChakraProvider>
      <Box p={5}>
        <Text fontSize="3xl" fontWeight="bold">Find Your Destination</Text>
        <Questionnaire onSubmit={handleSubmit} />
        {place && <Results place={place} />}
      </Box>
    </ChakraProvider>
  );
};

export default Home;

Issue Description

When submitting the form in the front end, I encounter the following error:

POST http://localhost:3000/api/match-places 500 (Internal Server Error)
AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 500', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_RESPONSE', ...}


It seems to always fail on this line:
const places = await Place.find({}).limit(10);

The server logs show:


Error during database operation:  MongooseError: Operation `places.find()` buffering timed out after 10000ms

What I tried

Ensured Connection is Established Before Querying:


Used async/await to ensure the connection is established before performing queries.Verified MongoDB Server is Running:


Checked MongoDB server status using sudo systemctl status mongod.


Connected to MongoDB using the MongoDB shell and verified that queries work fine:

mongosh
use NG_DESTINATION
db.places.find().limit(1)


Tested Database Connection with a Standalone Script:


Created and ran a standalone script (testConnectionDB.js) which connects to the database and performs a query successfully:

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const MONGO_URI = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/NG_DESTINATION';

const placeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  country: String,
  population: Number,
  work: {
    pub: Number,
    pub_ratio: Number,
    languages: {
      primary: String,
      secondary: String,
    },
    avg: Number,
    attendance: Number,
  },
  culture: {
    food_type: String,
    climate: String,
    internet_penetration: String,
    transportation_infra: String,
    crime_rate: String,
    recreation: String,
  },
});

const Place = mongoose.model('Place', placeSchema, 'places');

async function testConnection() {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(MONGO_URI);
    console.log('MongoDB connected');
    
    const places = await Place.find({ 'culture.recreation': 'Soccer' });
    console.log('Places found:', places);
    
    mongoose.connection.close();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error connecting to MongoDB:', error);
  }
}

testConnection();

Expectation

It should return the matching data to the screen from my local MongoDB database where:
'culture.recreation' = 'soccer'

